# flowjs: call of method `join`. Method cannot be called on mixed

Tags: javascript, types, casting, ecmascript-6, flowtype

Say I have a constant animals, which I import with

```
import animals from './animals
```

Say the animals constant is:

```
{
  hoofed:[
    'horses',
    'sheep',
    'goats'
],
  feline: [
  'lions',
  'tigers'
],
  canine: [
    'dogs',
    'wolves'
  ]
}
```

Say that I want to construct a Url query to some animals api, and write the following code:

```
const fq = Object.values(animals).reduce((memo, animalList) => memo + `animal:${animalList.join(' animal:')} `, '')
```

Now this code generates a string of animals, separated by the word animal and whitespace, which is then URL encoded and correctly matches the target API surface.

FlowJS however, rejects this code with:

```
13:   const fq = Object.values(animals).reduce((memo, animalList) => memo + `animal:${animalList.join(' animal:')} `, '')
                                                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ call of method `join`. Method cannot be called on
 13:   const fq = Object.values(animals).reduce((memo, animalList) => memo + `animal:${animalList.join(' animal:')} `, '')
                                                                                                ^^^^^^^^ mixed
```

My question is: why? The array is quite clearly not mixed, it is a constant, and Object.values *should* be returning something of type [string]?

What is flow detecting, and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Object.values` function returns an `Array<mixed>` type at the moment. So you need to cast it to an array of string arrays like the following.

```
let fq: string[][] = (Object.values(animals): any);

fq = fq
    .reduce((memo, animalList) => memo + `animal:${animalList.join(' animal:')} `, '')
```

Or use an inline cast like this:

```
const fq = ((Object.values(animals): any): string[][])
    .reduce((memo, animalList) => memo + `animal:${animalList.join(' animal:')} `, '')
```

Flow can't support this function at the moment out of the box, because the `Object.values` function is [in stage-4](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries) as a proposal. So it's not part of the language yet. It should be just a matter of time that you won't need to workaround this problem with a cast, as soon as the `Object.values` function is part of the EcmaScript standard, the flow team will probably implement it correctly.